# Checksums are different

Tags: installation, 13.10

The Ubuntu image file "ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso" which I've downloaded checksum is different. If I proceed to install will it get installed or not? Even if it gets installed will it work properly? Even if it is working properly will it be having all the functions? I had used "Orbit Downloader" to download the file. I had to pause & restart the download due to internet problems & while downloading I had accidently pressed the power button & Windows shut downed. Sorry for too many question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, you cannot install it If checksums are different. The Direct meaning for different checksums is your downloaded ISO of Ubuntu is broken.

Read this you will understand : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM